# Sanitize Variables in PHP to AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, scope

I have a long string that contains some weird characters and quotes similar to this:

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdewhriho "shfihewr32" fhihifhewt43t[sdfhiort]sfhishf"gg"fhdif

It's part of an object I have in my PHP file that was created at the start of my script and is stored in $song->lyrics property as a string. I've tried passing it to my AngularJS controller through this:

```
<div ng-controller="lyricsMod" ng-init="songInit('<?php echo $song->lyrics')">
```

This is my AngularJS controller:

```
displaySong.controller('lyricsMod', ['$scope', function($scope) {
//Set up initial scopes:
$scope.songInit = function(songLyrics) {
    $scope.lyrics = songLyrics;
}
```

But I keep getting this error from AngularJS:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr]
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated
```

I have tried using mysqli_real_escape_string on the string to no avail. The error seems to happen right when AngularJS hits the first quotation marks in the string. I've read you need to use sanitize on the string but I have no idea how to sanitize the string in PHP or HTML. Sorry if this is a noob question, Ijust started learning AngularJS. Is there a better practice to pass my PHP variables into AngularJS or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried giving a look at [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing your PHP code block (you're missing the `?>`).

Also, I believe it needs to be JSON encoded for the insertion into JS (which will also remove the need for quotes around the php block), and HTML entitized for insertion into a HTML attr:

```
<div ng-controller="lyricsMod" ng-init="songInit(<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($song->lyrics)); ?>)">
```